# Aggregating indicator metric in MicroStrategy Web 9.4.1

Tags: conditional-statements, aggregation, microstrategy

I am attempting to create a grid as follows:

Rows: Year

Columns: none

Metrics:

- Total Customers = Count of all CustomerIDs that are not in the Alaska/Hawaii region
- East Customers = Count of all CustomerIDs in the East region

Current Method:

Total Customers: For this, I simply use a Count of CustomerIDs and set the view filter on the grid to exclude customers from the Alaska/Hawaii region being counted in the metric. This works fine.

East Customers: For this, I created an indicator metric using the following steps. First, I create a metric from the Region attribute by using Max([Region]).  Then, I create a metric called East Indicator = IF((Max([Region])="East"),1,0).  Both of these steps work fine.  Then, I create a metric as SUM([East Indicator]).  However, when I drop the SUM([East Indicator]) metric into my grid, the value for each Year is 0 or 1, instead of the sum.  It seems like I may have a problem in terms of setting the level of my metrics.  I have tried to change the level but nothing works.

Is there a way for me to sum my indicator metric "East Indicator" by year?

Also, is it possible to create new attributes using Attribute Editor when the data is stored in an Intelligent Cube from an Excel file loaded via MicroStrategy Web?  If so, I could just create indicator attributes and sum those, which is what I did when I implemented this in MicroStrategy 10 Desktop Analytics trial tool. I am not sure if that is possible in MicroStrategy Enterprise 9.4.1.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you should use conditional metrics, but I'm not really sure if you are using only data imported from an Excel file or do you have a database?

Comment: as of now the data is imported from Excel into an Intelligent Cube. after more research it seems what I am trying to do is only possible if the data is stored in a database.  we are working on this.